# How can I understand the swap operator arising from the electron spin Hamiltonian $H_s(t)=J(t)\vec S_1\cdot\vec S_2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-computer

I am after basic quantum physics course and I am trying to understand [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.57.120) paper. I am focused now on swap operator defined there. Unitary time evolution operator:
$$U_s(t) = T exp(-i\int_0^t{H_s(t')dt'})$$
where:
$$H_s(t) = J(t)\vec{S}_1\vec{S}_2$$
after all mentioned in the paper substitutions we get swap operator:
$$U_s(J_0\tau_s = \pi)= U_{SW} = Te^{-i\pi\vec{S1}\vec{S2}} = -Te^{\vec{S_1}\vec{S_2}}$$
Now how can I "see" this operator swapping electrons' spins? I mean if wave function of two qubit system is $\psi = \alpha|\uparrow\uparrow⟩ + \beta|\downarrow\downarrow⟩ + \gamma|\downarrow\uparrow⟩ + \delta|\uparrow\downarrow⟩$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are probabilities of states. How applying swap operator to this wave function makes probabilities of swapped spins higher? I think that I really miss something in this thought process but I don't really know what. Can you please clarify how this swap operator can be applied in mentioned system of two qubits?

Comment: There might be problem with the last equality. Apart from that: you just act with this operator on the wave function...

Comment: Do you know how to compute the matrix exponential?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yes I do but I don't see any $e^{matrix}$ except if $\vec{S_1}\vec{S_2}$ is cross product and not dot product.

Comment: $\vec S_1\vec S_2$ is the "scalar product" of $\vec S \otimes I$  and $I\otimes \vec S$, that is, $\sum_\alpha (S_\alpha\otimes I)(I\otimes S_\alpha) = \sum_\alpha S_\alpha\otimes S_\alpha$ ($\alpha=x,y,z$). This is a $4\times 4$ matrix.  If you work out what this matrix is and exponentiate it with the correct time, you get an operator which acts by swapping the state of the two spins.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Great, thank you! That clarifies everything.

Comment: Great to hear it helped, I converted it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec S_1\vec S_2$ is the "scalar product" of $\vec S \otimes I$  and $I\otimes \vec S$, that is,
$$
\sum_\alpha (S_\alpha\otimes I)(I\otimes S_\alpha) = \sum_\alpha S_\alpha\otimes S_\alpha\quad (\alpha=x,y,z)\ .
$$

That is, $\vec S_1\vec S_2$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix.
If you work out what this matrix is and take the matrix exponential
$$\mathbb F = e^{-it\vec S_1\vec S_2}$$
with the correct time,
you get an operator $\mathbb F$ which acts by swapping the state of the two spins.